# How to pass the arrayList of records from a database to a table in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have some records in a table in MYSQL.

```
    public List<EmployeeTable> getEmployee() {
    ArrayList<EmployeeTable> empList = new ArrayList<EmployeeTable>();
    Connection con = (Connection) DbManager.getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement   pstmnt  = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select * from employeetable");
        ResultSet           rs      = pstmnt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            empList.add(new EmployeeTable(rs.getString("firstName"), 
                                          rs.getString("lastName"), 
                                          rs.getString("displayName"), 
                                          rs.getString("dob"), 
                                          rs.getString("email"), 
                                          rs.getString("password"), 
                                          rs.getString("contact")));
        }
        return empList;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

I want to put this retrieved arrayList into a table in a JSP.
I have tried to like this and couldn't understand how to proceed.

```
   <h2 align="center"><font><strong>Retrieve data from database in jsp</strong></font></h2>
<table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
<tr>

</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#A52A2A">
<td><b>id</b></td>
<td><b>firstName</b></td>
<td><b>lastName</b></td>
<td><b>displayName</b></td>
<td><b>email</b></td>
<td><b>password</b></td>
<td><b>contact</b></td>
</tr>
<%
try{ 
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId, password);
statement=connection.createStatement();
String sql ="SELECT * FROM record";

resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
while(resultSet.next()){
%>
<tr bgcolor="#DEB887">

<td><%=resultSet.getString("id") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("firstName") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("lastName") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("displayName") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("email") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("password") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("contact") %></td>
</tr>

<% 
}

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</table>
```

I understand that the above code is wrong but I gave it a try.
Can anyone tell me on how to do it in a correct way.

Comment: I am able to retrieve the records into an ArrayList using method: getEmployees() given above

Comment: You could have put the list into request or session and fetched over jsp.

Comment: Whats the **Error**..?

Comment: Why not read your records from a Dao in a Custom Tag handler and read them into a session variable. That way you don't need to worry about 'passing' potentially large quantities of data around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your db code to a Servlet. To give you an code example for the mentioned comments.

Servlet:

```
@Override
protected final void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   ...
   // fetch your data as list
   List<EmployeeTable> employees = getEmployee();

   //set attribute at request scope 
   request.setAttribute("employees", employees);

   // or at session scope
   request.getSession(true).setAttribute("employees", employees);

   // do redirect/forward to your jsp..
}

// probably your getEmployee() method
```

Access the list in your jsp this way..(imports omitted)

```
...
<%
List<EmployeeTable> list = request.getAttribute("employees"); 
// iterate through your list
%>
```

or better if you use EL expressions and want to iterate..

```
<!-- request scope -->
<c:forEach var="employee" items="${employees}">

<!-- for session scope --> 
<c:forEach var="employee" items="${sessionScope.employees}">
```

Comment: It helped a lot.Thank you.